# Image not displaying QT6 C++ Cmake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I'm currently recoding an old QT5 python project in QT6 with c++ and cmake. Everything is working pretty much fine, but when I try displaying images it wont show up.

So I just created a simple test program, with an image, and I can't get it to work.
I'm new to using qrc and not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.
It shows up in qt designer, but I know that doesn't mean much.
It seems like he is not finding the image, but there is no error or feedback in the terminal.

Here is what my project looks like:

**Main.qml:**

```
import QtQuick

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    color: "#c03434"
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        x: 79
        y: 57
        width: 483
        height: 367
        color: "#00ffffff"

        Image {
            id: image
            visible: true
            anchors.fill: parent
            source: ":/images/logo_white_100x100.png"
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
        }
    }
}
```

**CMakeList:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(biiiigtesterino VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt6 6.2 COMPONENTS Quick REQUIRED)

qt_add_executable(appbiiiigtesterino
    main.cpp
    res.qrc
)

qt_add_qml_module(appbiiiigtesterino
    URI biiiigtesterino
    VERSION 1.0
    QML_FILES main.qml 

)

set_target_properties(appbiiiigtesterino PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER my.example.com
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

target_compile_definitions(appbiiiigtesterino
    PRIVATE $<$<OR:$<CONFIG:Debug>,$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>>:QT_QML_DEBUG>)
target_link_libraries(appbiiiigtesterino
    PRIVATE Qt6::Quick)
```

**res.qrc:**

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/images">
        <file>logo_white_100x100.png</file>
        <file>main.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26125095/cant-load-image-source-in-qml-image), but it didn't help.
I appreciate any help, cause I'm desperate.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't be using a qrc with the new qt_add_qml_module

add the png file to the qt_add_qml_modules RESOURCES should fix it, you might have to adjust the path. It should be documented on the qt website. also checkout this blog they posted about it https://www.qt.io/blog/qml-modules-in-qt-6.2

Answer (score 0):

i have read in the documentation that you need to add this :

```
qt_add_resources(yourApp imageresources
    FILES
        folder_of_image/your_image.png
)
```

then you call it in an Image qml object :

```
Image {
   source: "qrc:/folder_of_image/your_image.png"
}
```

works for me. I hope this can help someone